# If/else statement: Search through multiple possible values only finds last value (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a form with various inputs to search an address. Only the province and postal code first appear when you load the page, but there is the option to open a toggle to display more options such as street name etc. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is for the toggle to remain open when the page loads again if the select and text inputs are not empty (' ' and 0).

I have most of the logic down, but my problem is that my if/else statement is only looking at the last value it is getting.

```
var allInputsValue;
var allInputs; //for testing purposes

$('.address-options').each(
    function(){
        allInputs = $(this); //for testing purposes
        allInputsValue = $(this).val();
        //console.log('Type: ' + allInputs.attr('type') + ' Name: ' + allInputs.attr('name') + ' Value: ' + allInputs.val());
        //console.log(' ID: ' + allInputs.attr('id') + '\n' + ' Value: ' + allInputs.val());
        console.log('Value: ' + allInputsValue);
    }
);

//if($('#civicNo').val() == '', $('#streetName').val() == ''){
if(allInputsValue === '' || allInputsValue === 0){
    alert("Empty fields");
    if (localStorage) {
        localStorage.setItem('addressOptions', 'closed');
    }
    togglePane("closed");
}else{
    alert("Fields not empty");

    if (localStorage) {
        localStorage.setItem('addressOptions', 'open');
    }
    togglePane("open");
}
```

I'm trying to keep the code fairly clean without having to do an else if for every input ID.

In the console log I get back all the correct values I am looking for. What am I missing?

Comment: You are overwriting your allInputsValue in each `.each()`. Either put the `if/else` in the `.each()`, or make it allInputsValue an array

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `if-else` inside `.each`

```
var allInputsValue;
    var allInputs; //for testing purposes

    $('.address-options').each(
            function(){
                allInputs = $(this); //for testing purposes
                allInputsValue = $(this).val();
                //console.log('Type: ' + allInputs.attr('type') + ' Name: ' + allInputs.attr('name') + ' Value: ' + allInputs.val());
                //console.log(' ID: ' + allInputs.attr('id') + '\n' + ' Value: ' + allInputs.val());
                console.log('Value: ' + allInputsValue);
//if($('#civicNo').val() == '', $('#streetName').val() == ''){
    if(allInputsValue === '' || allInputsValue === 0){
        alert("Empty fields");
        if (localStorage) {
            localStorage.setItem('addressOptions', 'closed');
        }
        togglePane("closed");
    }else{
        alert("Fields not empty");

        if (localStorage) {
            localStorage.setItem('addressOptions', 'open');
        }
        togglePane("open");
    }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Any idea why a value of 0 would result to field not empty? I also end up with 5 toggles with this solution  :/

Answer (score 1):

It could just be my eyes, but it looks like your if/else statement is outside the loop. It needs to be inside the loop

```
    var allInputsValue;
    var allInputs; //for testing purposes

    $('.address-options').each(
        function(){
            allInputs = $(this); //for testing purposes
            allInputsValue = $(this).val();
            //console.log('Type: ' + allInputs.attr('type') + ' Name: ' + allInputs.attr('name') + ' Value: ' + allInputs.val());
            //console.log(' ID: ' + allInputs.attr('id') + '\n' + ' Value: ' + allInputs.val());
            console.log('Value: ' + allInputsValue);
        }
   // ); This needs to be below

    //if($('#civicNo').val() == '', $('#streetName').val() == ''){
    if(allInputsValue === '' || allInputsValue === 0){
        alert("Empty fields");
        if (localStorage) {
            localStorage.setItem('addressOptions', 'closed');
        }
        togglePane("closed");
    }else{
        alert("Fields not empty");

        if (localStorage) {
            localStorage.setItem('addressOptions', 'open');
        }
        togglePane("open");
    }
**);**
```

Comment: Any idea why a value of 0 would result to field not empty? I also end up with 5 toggles with this solution  :/

Comment: @JessicaC Tried with `'0'` instead of just `0` in the `if` statement?

Comment: I feel silly for not trying that. Thanks! It fixed that issue. However now I have seven toggles that get created everytime the fields are open or empty... I didn't think about that, this logic may not work.